# SO(3) modded by a finite subgroup

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, orbifolds

Sorry for a probably naive question by a physicist. Suppose we consider SO(3) as a manifold and identify points which are equivalent under the action of some finite subgroup, say the rotations corresponding to symmetries of a tetrahedron. Is the resulting 'manifold' with points identified what people call an orbifold? Are all the homotopy groups of this object well known?

Comment: Finite subgroups of $SO(3)$ are discrete and act freely on it, so the quotient should actually be a manifold. You could probably get better descriptions of them by passing to $S^3$, or at least the homotopy groups using the homotopy long exact sequence.

Comment: the low budget aspect of this is that your group is double covered by the unit quaternions; given a vector, which is here a quaternion with real part zero, then a unit quaternion $q,$ the rotated vector is $q v \bar{q}$ which has again real part zero

Comment: @WillJagy, Yes I realized by runway44's comment that it's safe to use $S^3$ (your unit $q$ except not necessarily real part zero) since for a finite group like the symmetries of the tetrahedron the $q$ are already identified before we can reach $-q$ (which is what matters for the difference between $S^3$ and $SO(3)$.

Comment: @octonion good. I once asked a question om MO with title: Octonions and the dance of the seven veils. A year or two later, some idiot changed the title.

Comment: @WillJagy, Haha, some people have no sense of humor